Docker not launching Blazor WebAssembly App .NET 8 as expected
I've recently created a new Blazor web assembly app and added Docker support to the project. Then, I performed the following steps to build and run the container:

Build Docker image:
docker build -t blazorapp .

Run container:
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name myblazorapp blazorapp

However, after executing these commands, nothing happens. I expected the application to run and be accessible via port 8080, but this is not occurring.
Here's the content of my Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["BlazorApp2/BlazorApp2.csproj", "BlazorApp2/"]
COPY ["BlazorApp2.Client/BlazorApp2.Client.csproj", "BlazorApp2.Client/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./BlazorApp2/BlazorApp2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/BlazorApp2"
RUN dotnet build "./BlazorApp2.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./BlazorApp2.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BlazorApp2.dll"]

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Seem the dockfile donwload/copy from some where will cause this issue. I have verify it and it can be fix by following ways.

Step 1. Delete dockerfile present in the project.
Step 2. Right click on the project > add > Docker support.


After adding the docker support, we can run it successfully. (I am using Docker Desktop Application)
By the way, we still need to double-check the settings is correct or not. Here is my docker file.
dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["BlazorApp2/BlazorApp2.csproj", "BlazorApp2/"]
COPY ["BlazorApp2.Client/BlazorApp2.Client.csproj", "BlazorApp2.Client/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./BlazorApp2/BlazorApp2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/BlazorApp2"
RUN dotnet build "./BlazorApp2.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./BlazorApp2.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BlazorApp2.dll"]

.csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>c49f1cd2-b077-4f7d-a365-6b50919c5638</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\BlazorApp2.Client\BlazorApp2.Client.csproj" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.21.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

launchSettings.json
{
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5298"
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7077;http://localhost:5298"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}"
    },
    "Container (Dockerfile)": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS": "8081",
        "ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS": "8080"
      },
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:30184",
      "sslPort": 44386
    }
  }
}

Test Result

